# Why is datetime in tooltip formatting returning 2tB?

Tags: bokeh

At the moment all of my dates in the tooltip are being returned as Epoch figures, i.e. 1560846380

I've tried

```
tooltips=[('Date', '@x{datetime}')...])
```

but I'm getting "2tB" as a result.

My tooltip code:

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Date', '@x{datetime}'), ("Count", "@y")]) 

# This also doesn't work: formatters={'x': 'datetime'}
```

Why is 'datetime' returning "2tB" and not a dd/mm/yyyy?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in the curly braces is a format specified, e.g. `%F`. The string "datetime" is not a valid datetime format, so the result is undefined. A correct specification would look more like:

```
HoverTool(
    tooltips=[( 'Date', '@x{%F}' )],

    formatters={
        'x' : 'datetime'  # use 'datetime' formatter for 'x' field
    }
)
```

If you refer to [Formatting Tooltip Fields](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields) you can see more information.

---

*IMPORTANT NOTE: In Bokeh 2.0 the `formatters` field will require the key to match the tooltip exactly, including the `@` symbol:*

```
formatters={
    # The matching @ be required starting with Bokeh 2.0
    '@x' : 'datetime'
},
```